# Conditional formatting a cell based on if a certain string is found in multiple cells?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

This is something I've not found and for the life of me cannot come up without help.

I have a single "Overall status" cell in my Google Sheet, which should turn green, if/when a certain number of other cells in the same sheet have their statuses as "Ready" (text string "Ready" in the cell). So, the formula should check the string "ready" from several different cells in the same sheet.

How could I achieve this? I've tried to solve this by adapting the other related examples, but either my syntax is wrong or somethin else is not quite right :/

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

If your Ready data is in cells A1:J1 and you want to highlight your Overall Status cell when you have the word ready more that 4 times you can use the following formula in a conditional rule.

With the format cell option set to Custom Formula is

```
=countifs(A1:J1,"Ready")>=4
```

[image]